# Would browsers set If-Modified-Since or If-None-Match header in the new request after being redirected?

Tags: http, cache-control, http-caching

So I'm testing with this setup. `https://example.com/original` always responds with a 308 status code, redirecting the browser to `https://example.com/new`.
`https://example.com/new` checks if `If-Modified-Since` and `If-None-Match` to see if cache is still valid, and returns 304 if so. Otherwise it should return 200 with the full content and ETag, Last-Modified in response header.

What I'm seeing is that after being redirected, however many times I try, in the new request to `https://example.com/new` the browser does not have `If-Modified-Since` or `If-None-Match` set. Thus the server always return 200 with the full content. It feels like browser just does not try to remember ETag or `Last-Modified` returned by `https://example.com/new`.

Is it possible for the redirect response (`https://example.com/original` which returns 308) to tell the browser to remember ETag or Last-Modified so it can include If-Modified-Since or If-None-Match in the request to `https://example.com/new`?

Comment: Why would a user hit this redirect multiple times?

Comment: @StephenOstermiller you can try [link](https://celestia.mobi). the resource in the websites have redirects. `https://celestia.mobi/css/styles-v12.css` will redirect to `https://cdn.astroweather.cn/celestia/v1/css/styles-v12.css`, try navigating between the tabs and you'll see the redirected resource being requested in full repeatedly.

Comment: edit, I've changed `https://celestia.mobi/css/styles-v13.css` to not redirect. But you can still check out `https://celestia.mobi/img/appicon.jpg` loaded by `https://celestia.mobi` which is still a redirect.

Comment: Why wouldn't your site link directly to the image on the CDN?

Comment: @StephenOstermiller thanks for the reply. I could but I have some pages that already referenced the link `https://celestia.mobi/img/appicon.jpg` using `/img/appicon.jpg` so I did redirect instead, also this makes changing cdn easier, I just have to rewrite the redirect logic while keep the existing links in many pages, is it a bad practice to do so?

Comment: Yes, it is bad practice. It may contribute to your caching problem.  It makes your site slower.  It increases the load on your origin server.  It reduces the effectiveness of your CDN.